# Assembly - Can't properly compile the code

Tags: assembly, irvine32

New to assembly. I've been given this code to build and debug it with the purpose of studying it. The build went fine, but when debugging, I keep getting an error telling: "`Unhandled exception at 0x00401035 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00804002.`" at line 16, I don't know if the same kind of error would reappear if that one would be fixed.

Here's the code below, ignore the deleted comments, they were made in my native language, which is not English:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
alfa    DW    3 DUP(?)
.code
main proc
mov    ax,17  ; 
mov    ax,10101b   ;
mov    ax,11b         ;
mov    ax,21o         ;
mov    alfa,ax          ; 
mov    cx,ax      ; 
mov    ax,bx      ; 
mov    ax,cx      ;
xchg   ax,bx      ; 
mov   si,2
mov   alfa[si],ax  ; LINE 16
mov   esi,2
mov   ebx,offset alfa ; 
lea   ebx,alfa        ; 
mov     ecx,[ebx][esi]  ; 
mov     cx,alfa[2]   ; 
mov     cx,[alfa+2]  ; 
mov     di,4
mov     byte ptr [ebx][edi],55h  ;
mov     esi,2
mov     ebx,3
mov     alfa[ebx][esi],33h  ; 
                                    
mov     alfa[ebx+esi],33h   
mov     [alfa+ebx+esi],33h
mov     [ebx][esi]+alfa,33h

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: `mov   alfa[si],ax` is using 16 bit addressing. You want `mov alfa[esi]` and load `esi` beforehand. The only strange thing is the error mentions a 32 bit address ... hmmm...

Comment: Changing it to `esi` didn't quite help, still getting the error, maybe because I didn't load `esi`, but, since I'm completely new to this, I don't know how to do it ;D

Comment: Move the following up (the `mov esi,2`).

Comment: Now the program dies at the line 24 :D,  `byte ptr [ebx][edi],55h`

Comment: `mov di,4` should be `mov edi,4`